# Python throwing strange NameError: name <function_name> is not defined

Tags: python

```
import networkx as nx #@UnresolvedImport
from networkx.algorithms import bipartite #@UnresolvedImport
from operator import itemgetter
from random import choice

corpus = open('/home/abehl/Desktop/Corpus/songs.wx', 'r')

ALPHA = 1.5
EPSILON = 0.5

song_nodes = []
word_nodes = []    

edges = zip(song_nodes, word_nodes)

B = nx.Graph(edges)
degX,degY = bipartite.degrees(B, word_nodes)

sortedSongNodesByDegree = sorted(degX.iteritems(), key=itemgetter(1))
print sortedSongNodesByDegree

song_nodes2 = []
word_nodes2 = []
Vc = list(set(word_nodes))

edges2 = zip(song_nodes2, word_nodes2)
C= nx.Graph(edges2)

for songDegreeTuple in sortedSongNodesByDegree:
    for i in range(songDegreeTuple[1]):
        connectedNodes = C.neighbors(songDegreeTuple[0])
        VcDash = [element for element in Vc if element not in connectedNodes]
        calculateBestNode(VcDash)

def calculateBestNode(VcDashsR):
    nodeToProbailityDict = {}
    for node in VcDashsR:
        degreeOfNode = bipartite(C, [node])[1][node]
        probabiltyForNode = (degreeOfNode ** ALPHA) + EPSILON
        nodeToProbailityDict[node] = probabiltyForNode
```

In the above python program, python interpreter is throwing the following error even though the function 'calculateBestNode' is defined in the program. Am I missing something here.

> NameError: name
>   'calculateBestNode' is not defined

Pardon me for posting a large program here.

Comment: I don't see a calculateSelectedNode function

Comment: calculateSelectedNode isn't anywhere in your program

Comment: I have updated the error message, had posted the wrong one here.

Comment: You call it before you declare it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A Python program is executed from top to bottom, so you need to define the function before you use it. A common alternative is putting all the code that is automatically executed in a `main` function, and adding at the bottom of the file:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This has the additional advantage that you have now written a module that can be imported by others.

Comment: The parsing isn't relevant: the entire module is parsed before any of it is executed. What is relevant is that in Python functions are created when the `def` is executed in the normal flow of the program.

Answer (score 3):

You try to use the function `calculateBestNode()` before you define it in your program. So the interpreter doesn't know it exists.